# Duplicate content in the feed, should it really be like this?

Tags: bug, android-app

I use the Stack Exchange Android App (version 1.0.51) on my Nexus 5 (Android-version 5.0.1).

In the feed section, I can see two lines with the exact the same post.
Should it really be like this or is there a bug within the feed?

[image: screenshot where you can see the duplicate content]

The screenshot shows the same posts within the "Earlier this month" section.

In the section "Earlier this year" are also two lines with the same posts but one difference to the section above.
In this section the count of the answers don't match and the icon is missing (see my hand-drawn circles ;-)).

[image]

Comment: No hand-drawn circles? Its going to be declined for sure!

Comment: I revised my question and added a few hand-drawn circles. hope it will not be declined anymore.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should not be like this. Two things are happening here:

1. The first screenshot shows two identical rows on-top of each other. This is a race condition on the APIs side, I believe. For now we should be checking this locally and stopping it from being displayed.
2. The second screenshot shows something a lot more complex. The same question is showing up under "Hot Questions" on two different rows. What's making this rough is that different calls to the feed generation logic don't know what's displayed earlier for you, so it has duplicates.

   The count of answers is different on them simply because the count of answers was different on the questions the two different times they were deemed qualified to show up in your feed. This is a really big rework to get right, and the person who owns the feed is currently working on other things so I don't think this will be fixed anytime soon.

I'm going to leave this question open until the client side fix for #1 is done.